# Can I convert DeviceGray colorspace to DeviceRGB in vb.net?

Tags: colors, itext7, pdf-extraction

I need to convert DeviceGray Colorspace to DeviceRGB Colorspace while using itext7 to extract pdf contents, Is it possible ?

Comment: You mean that you have extracted DeviceGray color values and want equivalent DeviceRGB values? Or do you actually need to replace setting instructions in the pdf content streams?

Comment: Yes I have extracted DeviceGray color values and now want equivalent DeviceRGB.

Comment: for now I have used 
Dim RGBcolor As itext.kernel.colors.color.Devicergb 
Dim colorvalue As Double = pathRenderInfo.GetFillColor.GetColorValue(0)
   Dim colorvalues() As Single = {colorvalue, colorvalue, colorvalue}
           RGBcolor.SetColorValue(colorvalues)

Comment: That should be correct.